# Unable to find Button python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, button, syntax-error

This code:

```
bump = driver.find_element_by_class_name("rlg-trade__action rlg-trade__bump --bump ")
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAzne.png)

Generates this error:
Unable to locate element:

```
{"method":"css selector","selector":".rlg-trade__action rlg-trade__bump --bump "}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKZND.png)

Here's the HTML code:
[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKNQS.png)

Comment: Please don't provide text information as images. Encode the text (error trace, HTML) embedded in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you notice on the error message that Selenium appended a `.` to the class name. So doing this:

```py
driver.find_element_by_class_name("rlg-trade__action rlg-trade__bump --bump ")
```

Made Selenium look for an element which matched this selector:

```css
.rlg-trade__action rlg-trade__bump --bump
```

When what you wanted was something like this:

```css
.rlg-trade__action.rlg-trade__bump.--bump
```

If you look the documentation up, it seems that [`find_element_by_class_name` only allows you to find an element by a single classname](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name).

So if you really want to go around this by using that selector, maybe [`find_element_by_css_selector` makes more sense](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector):

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.rlg-trade__action.rlg-trade__bump.--bump')
```